# Ruby on Rails: before_save fields to lowercase

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, sqlite, activerecord

I'm trying to change the fields from the form to lower case before they get saved in the database. This is my code but the output from the database is still in upper case why isnt the code working?

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
   validates :name, presence: true
   validates :amount, presence: true, numericality: true
   before_save :downcase_fields

   def downcase_fields
      self.name.downcase
   end
end
```

Comment: before_save { |transaction| transaction.name.downcase! }

Comment: This is an old question, but I think it's worth pointing out this idea has unintended consequences. If you wait to downcase something like `name`, you can't actually get the uniqueness constraint you think you're getting. This complicates things for your client. You probably want to combine this with case insensitivity in your uniqueness validator.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`downcase` returns a copy of the string, doesn't modify the string itself. Use `downcase!` instead:

```
def downcase_fields
  self.name.downcase!
end
```

See [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-downcase) for more details.

Comment: This worked for me, I just had to add the safe navigation operator `&` to make ir work properly when the name is `nil` in one of my rspec spec.
`self.name&.downcase!`

Answer (score 7):

You're not setting `name` to downcase by running `self.name.downcase`, because `#downcase` does not modify the string, it returns it. You should use the bang `downcase` method

```
self.name.downcase!
```

However, there's another way I like to do it in the model:

```
before_save { name.downcase! }
```

Answer (score 4):

`String#downcase` does not mutate the string, it simply returns a modified copy of that string. As others said, you could use the `downcase!` method.

```
def downcase_fields
  name.downcase!
end
```

However, if you wanted to stick with the `downcase` method, then you could do the following:

```
def downcase_fields
  self.name = name.downcase
end
```

This reassigns the name instance variable to the result of calling downcase on the original value of name.

Answer (score 4):

Other simple example with less code:

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
   validates :name, presence: true
   validates :amount, presence: true, numericality: true

   before_save { self.name.downcase!}

end
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: redundant `self` you can avoid it  
`before_save { name.downcase! }`

Answer (score 2):

You need to use exclamation mark after calling method *downcase*, if you also want to save result of operation to the variable.
So for you will be usable:

```
self.name.downcase!
```

Don't forget that *.downcase!* replacement works only in ASCII region.

Answer (score -7):

Another solution is to remove the `before_save` and monkeypatch the `initialize` method

```ruby
def initialize(args = {})
  args[:name].downcase! if args[:name]
  super
end
```

Then you can say something like

```
irb(main)> t = Transaction.new name: 'BIGTRANSACTION'

irb(main)> t.name

=> "bigtransaction"
```

This solution edits the behavior at instantiation instead of at creation, which can be useful if you need to check the edited value before saving anything to the database. For example, if you also need to run validations on the attribute.

Comment: @Yoni that's why we use `super`. it makes sure previous behavior is kept by running the previous definition of `initialize`.